# How to use assign instead of memcpy

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

I learned `memcpy` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)

The demo shows `memcpy` is much like `assign`

---

How to use assign instead of memcpy

```
- (uint64_t)parseHeader:(NSData *)data {

    uint64_t headerLength = 0;
    memcpy(&headerLength, data.bytes, sizeof(uint64_t));
 // set a breakpoint
    return headerLength;
}
```

I suppose that `headerLength` should equal to `(uint64_t)(data.bytes)`

And I `p` at that breakpoint

here is the result:

```
(lldb) p headerLength
(uint64_t) $0 = 318
(lldb) p data.bytes
(const void *) $1 = 0x00006000000050e0
(lldb) p (uint64_t)(data.bytes)
(uint64_t) $2 = 105553116287200
```

So how to understand `memcpy` in this context?

I want to use more OOP to get rid of `memcpy`

---

***More Code:***

I encounter this when learning `GCDAsyncSocket`

The above is the receiving data part.

The sending data part:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PacketType){
    PacketTypeUnknown = -1,
    PacketTypeDidAddDisc,
    PacketTypeStartNewGame
};



typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PacketAction){
    PacketActionUnknown = -1
};

@interface PacketH: NSObject<NSSecureCoding>

@property (strong, nonatomic) id data;
@property (assign, nonatomic) PacketType type;
@property (assign, nonatomic) PacketAction action;


@end



- (void)sendPacket:(PacketH *)packet {

    // Encode Packet Data
    NSError * error;
    NSData * encoded = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:packet requiringSecureCoding:NO error: &error];
    // Initialize Buffer
    NSMutableData *buffer = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    // buffer = header + packet

    // Fill Buffer

    uint64_t headerLength = encoded.length;
    [buffer appendBytes:&headerLength length:sizeof(uint64_t)];
    [buffer appendBytes: encoded.bytes length: headerLength];

    // Write Buffer
    [self.socket writeData:buffer withTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];
}
```

Comment: You might be interested in the `getBytes:length:` method of NSData

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @user3386109,

`getBytes:length:` method of `NSData` , is much like `memcpy`

```
- (uint64_t)parseHeader:(NSData *)data {
    NSInteger headerLength = 0;
    [data getBytes: &headerLength length:sizeof(uint64_t)];
    return headerLength;
}
```